# Getting type error :this.props.getMovieTree is not a function

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, typeerror

I am new to the react native & redux trying to call a function but its giving me an error:

```
 this.prop.getMovieTree is undefined.
```

When I double click on the getmovietree it redirects me to proper function. But it is giving an error on runtime & crashes my app. When I `console.log(this.props)` it prints defined value but when I print console.log(this.props.getMovieTree()) this prints undefined.

// IN App.js:

```
import {getMovieTree} from './src/actions/RestActions'
export class App extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    getMovieTree: PropTypes.func,
  };
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
   }
componentWillMount()
{
this.props.getMovieTree();//at this line getting error: getmovietree() is undefined

}
}
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  const { movieList } = state;

  return {movieList};
};
export default connect(mapStateToProps,getMovieTree )(App);
```

//  In RestAction.js file:

```
import {MAGENTO_GET_MOVIE_TREE} from './types'
import {magento} from '../magento'
  export const getMovieTree = () => {
  return async dispatch => {
    try {
      const customer = await magento.getMovieTreeCall();
      dispatch({
        type: MAGENTO_GET_MOVIE_TREE,
        payload: customer
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
};
```

// In Index.js:

```
export default magento => {
return{
    getMovieTreeCall : () => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
         // const path = '/V1/AppVersion/';

          magento
            .send()
            .then(data => {
              resolve(data);

            })
            .catch(e => {
              console.log(e);
              reject(e);
            });
        });
      },
};


};



In magento/index.js:




class Magento {

    send(){

        fetch("https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/now_playing?api_key=55957fcf3ba81b137f8fc01ac5a31fb5&language=en-US")
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {
            return response.json()
            // this.setState({
            //     loading: false,
            //     dataSource: responseJson.results
            // })
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error))
    }


}

export const magento = new Magento();
```

Answer (score 2):

- First of all in Magento class you should use await or Promise to handle asynchronous task. The method should be like this :

```
    async send(){
            await fetch("https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/now_playing?api_key=55957fcf3ba81b137f8fc01ac5a31fb5&language=en-US")
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then((responseJson) => {
                return response.json()
                // this.setState({
                //     loading: false,
                //     dataSource: responseJson.results
                // })
            })
            .catch(error => console.log(error))
        }
    }
```

- Then you should map dispatch to props and then connect it to component :

```
    const mapStateToProps = state => ({ getMovieTree: state.getMovieTree })
    //OR
    const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
        return {
            getMovieTree: () => dispatch({  }) ///your desired action
        }
    }

    export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

In this case we don't need mapDispatchToProps you can easily call `getMovieTree` from props. The second arg for connect() is mapDispatchProps and can be undefined like this.

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App);
```

Comment: Thnks for your response but I am getting error in componentwillmount function on: componentWillMount()
{
this.props.getMovieTree();//at this line getting error: getmovietree() is undefined

} can you tell me whats wrong here?

Comment: I have just mentioned above that you did not map state to props properly. You have sent `movieList` prop to component. This can cause undefined prop error !